# Docker-Machine provisioned aws instance can not start docker engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

When I start a EC2 Instance with

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-region eu-central-1  --amazonec2-instance-type t2.2xlarge aws-test
```

docker-machine can create the VM, exchange the certs but the start of the engine fails.

Log in the EC2:

```html
ubuntu@aws-manager2:~$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─10-machine.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-29 09:18:44 UTC
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5263 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:/
 Main PID: 5263 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Cont
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed sta
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exi
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time o
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container En
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated 
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Cont
lines 1-16/16 (END)...skipping...
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─10-machine.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-29 09:18:44 UTC; 1min 53s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5263 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --s
 Main PID: 5263 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 29 09:18:44 aws-manager2 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Log at startup:

```html
$ docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-region eu-central-1  --amazonec2-instance-type t2.2xlarge aws-manager2
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(aws-manager2) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with ubuntu(systemd)...
Installing Docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: ssh command error:
command : sudo systemctl -f start docker
err     : exit status 1
output  : Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Yesterday it worked with the same configuration. Could there be a change in the used AIM since yesterday? I tried it from a different host but get also the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a bug in the Docker Version that was rollout yesterday. A Workaround for us:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --engine-install-url=https://web.archive.org/web/20170623081500/https://get.docker.com
```